# Underline issue with Inconsolata font

Tags: fonts, display

I'm using `Inconsolata` font in emacs. The setting looks like

```el
(set-face-attribute
   'default nil
   :font (font-spec :name "-*-Inconsolata-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"
                    :weight 'normal
                    :slant 'normal
                    :size 12.0))
```

But the wave style underline has some issue like

[image]

The bottom of the underline is strip by the next line. Using `Iosevka` everything is just fine

[image]

How can I fixed this without changing to another font? Changing the font size doesn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the “issue”?

Comment: @db48xThe bottom of the underline is strip by the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem with Emacs. All that is happening is that the font metrics for the font you've chosen don't leave quite enough room for the wavy underlines (the descenders are not quite as tall as the wavy underline). You could increase the line spacing of the face to compensate. I suppose it would be a little nicer if Emacs drew the wavy underline in a second pass after it had drawn all of the text, but that's a lot of complications for a very minor graphical difference.

Comment: Please consider adding info about how to increase the line spacing to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing `(setq-default line-spacing 0.25)` might solve your problem (`0.25` is just an dummy number, you'll need to adjust this). There's more information about line-height at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Line-Height.html (or directly in Emacs, of course: `M-x info-emacs-manual`).